# The block template file didn't call in my controller?

Tags: extensions, blocks, controllers

I can post my code. it's working controller and also block file but template File not working.

Sending code here.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
/**
* Module Configuration
*
*@author Magento
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentostudy_News>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Magentostudy_News>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <magentostudy_news>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                <module>Magentostudy_News</module>
                <frontName>news</frontName>
                </args>
            </magentostudy_news>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <layout>
            <updates>
            <magentostudy_news>
            <file>news.xml</file>
            </magentostudy_news>
            </updates>
    </layout>

    <global>
         <blocks>
                <news><class>Magentostudy_News_Block</class></news>
         </blocks>

    </global>

</config>
```

My news.xml file

```
    <layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="content"></reference>
</default>
<news_index_index>
    <reference name="content">

    <block type="news/news" name="news.slider" template="news/news.phtml"></block>

    </reference>

</news_index_index>
<layout>
```

This is My controller file

```
    <?php

class Magentostudy_News_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function _construct(){


      Mage::app()->loadArea($this->getLayout()->getArea());

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();


    }

    public function indexAction(){


       $cpBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('Magentostudy_News_Block_News');

    }

}

?>
```

This is My Block file

```
    <?php

class Magentostudy_News_Block_News extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{

    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        $this->setTemplate('news/news.phtml'); 
    }



}

?>
```

Tell me What type of issue in this file? and how to slove it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what tutorial you are using, but it seem a little overly complicated than it need to be. Take a look at [How to create front-end module in Magento](http://magentomaster.wordpress.com/2012/11/14/how-to-create-front-end-module-in-magento/)

In your controller all you need to do is

```
<?php
class Company_Web_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
      $this->loadLayout();     
      $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

In you DO NOT have a news.xml file then in your controller you could

```
   $this->loadLayout();       
   $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($this->getLayout()->createBlock('magentostudy/news_news'));
    $this->renderLayout();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not loading and rendering layouts in your `indexAction()`. It should look like this.

```
<?php
public function indexAction() 
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    //your custom changes should do here
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Without doing this, Magento will not render blocks inside the handle `news_index_index`.

I am totally not understanding why you are loading and rendering layout through `__construct()`. I think, you should not do that.

Also, you have already specified your template in layout file. So it is not necessary to define same template for your block through backend. ie via `Magentostudy_News_Block_News::_construct()`. Remove that part

Comment: Remove _construct in my block and also set in new code in indexcontrller           `$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
            'Magentostudy_News_Block_News',
            array('template' => 'news/news.phtml')
        ); 
          

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('core/session');
        $this->renderLayout();`

Comment: but its not working also change in xml file

Comment: `<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="content"></reference>


    <reference name="content">
    
    <block type="news/news" name="news.slider" template="news/news.phtml"></block>
    
    </reference>
  </default>  

<layout>`

Comment: `Call to a member function append() on a non-object` error is display

Comment: no you dont need to put anything extra in `indexAction`. JUst loadLayout and renderLayout enough

Comment: but not working i will try

Comment: comment out loadLayout and renderLayout in __cosntruct() in controller and then try again.NOte indexAction should look like what I shown in my answer

Comment: Not Working yarr

Comment: make sure controller is invoking. put `die()` inside `indexAction()` and tell me the result